# How to count unique values ​with the QUERY function of google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with a case similar to the following table:

| Producto | Referencia | Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCTO 1 | 1001 | 35 |
| PRODUCTO 1 | 1001 | 29 |

I am using the QUERY formula and I need the following result:

| group by Producto | count Referencia | count unique Referencia | sum Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCTO 1 |  |  |  |
| PRODUCTO 2 |  |  |  |
| PRODUCTO 3 |  |  |  |

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your locale, try:

```
=arrayformula(query({A:C\if(countifs(A:A&"-"&B:B;A:A&"-"&B:B;row(B:B);"<="&row(B:B))=1;1;)};"select Col1,count(Col2),sum(Col4),sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'group by Producto',sum(Col4) 'count unique Referencia' ";1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if the quantity column did not exist and I only wanted 'group by Producto', 'count Referencia' and 'count unique Referencia' columns?

Comment: `=arrayformula(query({A:C,if(countifs(A:A&"-"&B:B,A:A&"-"&B:B,row(B:B),"<="&row(B:B))=1,1,)},"select Col1,count(Col2),sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'group by Producto',sum(Col4) 'count unique Referencia' ",1))`